# Trio: why are channels documented as using `async with`, rather than `with`?

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, python-trio

Relevant documentation: https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#synchronizing-and-communicating-between-tasks

Relevant code: https://github.com/python-trio/trio/blob/master/trio/_channel.py

The documentation mentions, in `close()` docs, that "Using `with receive_channel:` will close the channel object on leaving the with block". On the other hand, the following section of the docs demonstrating the interface exclusively uses `async with receive_channel:` where the `close()` docs used regular `with`.

As per the code link, the relevant classes only have `__enter__` and `__exit__`, there's no `__aenter__` or `__aexit__`. So why does the demonstration in the docs use only `async with`? If I use regular `with` in my code, do I run the risk of future api changes breaking my code or some such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this is to aid refactoring, and generally to promote loose coupling via [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle).
The `producer` and `consumer` functions in the [*simple channel* example](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#a-simple-channel-example) from the docs do take an *arbitrary* [`SendChannel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.SendChannel) and [`ReceiveChannel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.ReceiveChannel) respectively, not a memory channel specifically - admittedly it's hard to see given the lack of type annocations :-P

> [`SendChannel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.SendChannel) / [`ReceiveChannel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.ReceiveChannel) objects also implement the [`AsyncResource`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.AsyncResource) interface, so they can be closed by calling [`aclose`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.AsyncResource.aclose) or using an `async with` block.

The [documentation of `MemoryReceiveChannel.close`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-core.html#trio.MemoryReceiveChannel.close) that you already quoted states explicitly

> All channel objects have an asynchronous [`aclose`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.abc.AsyncResource.aclose) method. Memory channels can **also** be closed synchronously.
>
> <sup>*(emphasis mine)*</sup>

So you can use normal `with` blocks and the `close()` method just fine with memory channels, there is no risk of breaking API changes. But if you ever want to change or reuse your code to work with a different channel implementation, say, a [`DTLSChannel`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-io.html#trio.DTLSChannel) or a web socket, you will prefer to have used `async with` in the first place.

Comment: aha, i had indeed missed the fact that memory channels are indeed merely one implemenation of broader abstract interfaces. thanks